# How to get Phaser 3 to output final score

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, phaser-framework

I'm creating my first Phaser 3 game and I need to output the final score to be used by another .js file that will output to a mysql database. I also need to be able to import the current highscore from said database into the phaser game.

final score is stores and var finalScore
database table name is highScores with the columns id, userName, score, date (date is so we can sort high scores by all time high scores, monthly high scores and daily high scores)

But I just need help getting the finalScore out of phaser and currentHighScore into phaser

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 10</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        var config = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            physics: {
                default: 'arcade',
                arcade: {
                    gravity: { y: 300 },
                    debug: false
                }
            },
            scene: {
                preload: preload,
                create: create,
                update: update
            }
        };

        var player;
        var stars;
        var bombs;
        var platforms;
        var cursors;
        var score = 0;
        var gameOver = false;
        var scoreText;
        // var userName;

        var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

        function preload() {
            this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
            this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
            this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
            this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
            this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
        }

        function create() {
            //  A simple background for our game
            this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

            //  The platforms group contains the ground and the 2 ledges we can jump on
            platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

            //  Here we create the ground.
            //  Scale it to fit the width of the game (the original sprite is 400x32 in size)
            platforms.create(400, 568, 'ground').setScale(2).refreshBody();

            //  Now let's create some ledges
            platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground');
            platforms.create(50, 250, 'ground');
            platforms.create(750, 220, 'ground');

            // The player and its settings
            player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude');

            //  Player physics properties. Give the little guy a slight bounce.
            player.setBounce(0.2);
            player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

            //  Our player animations, turning, walking left and walking right.
            this.anims.create({
                key: 'left',
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1
            });

            this.anims.create({
                key: 'turn',
                frames: [{ key: 'dude', frame: 4 }],
                frameRate: 20
            });

            this.anims.create({
                key: 'right',
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1
            });

            //  Input Events
            cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

            //  Some stars to collect, 12 in total, evenly spaced 70 pixels apart along the x axis
            stars = this.physics.add.group({
                key: 'star',
                repeat: 11,
                setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 70 }
            });

            stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

                //  Give each star a slightly different bounce
                child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));

            });

            bombs = this.physics.add.group();

            //  The score
            scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });

            //  Collide the player and the stars with the platforms
            this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
            this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);
            this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);

            //  Checks to see if the player overlaps with any of the stars, if he does call the collectStar function
            this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);

            this.physics.add.collider(player, bombs, hitBomb, null, this);
        }

        function update() {
            if (gameOver) {
                var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now()) / 1000;
                // gets the userName from the player

                var userName = prompt("Please enter your name", "name");
                //localStorage.setItem("playerName", userName);

                // Save score to final score, score will be reset to zero when game restarts 
                finalScore = score;
                console.log("User: " + userName + "'s score is " + finalScore + " at " + timeStamp + ".");

                // Reset gameOver to prevent update() loop and prepare game to restart
                gameOver = false;
                window.confirm("Would you like to play again?");
                // add call to start function again
                // if (confirm("Press a button!")) {
                //     this.game.state.restart()
                // } else {
                return;
                // }
            }

            if (cursors.left.isDown) {
                player.setVelocityX(-160);

                player.anims.play('left', true);
            }
            else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
                player.setVelocityX(160);

                player.anims.play('right', true);
            }
            else {
                player.setVelocityX(0);

                player.anims.play('turn');
            }

            if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
                player.setVelocityY(-330);
            }
        }

        function collectStar(player, star) {
            star.disableBody(true, true);

            //  Add and update the score
            score += 10;
            scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);

            if (stars.countActive(true) === 0) {
                //  A new batch of stars to collect
                stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

                    child.enableBody(true, child.x, 0, true, true);

                });

                var x = (player.x < 400) ? Phaser.Math.Between(400, 800) : Phaser.Math.Between(0, 400);

                var bomb = bombs.create(x, 16, 'bomb');
                bomb.setBounce(1);
                bomb.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
                bomb.setVelocity(Phaser.Math.Between(-200, 200), 20);
                bomb.allowGravity = false;

            }
        }

        function hitBomb(player, bomb) {
            this.physics.pause();

            player.setTint(0xff0000);

            player.anims.play('turn');

            gameOver = true;
        }

        // Function to post data to database
        // need to get api input format from Zack
        module.exports = {
                    userName: userName,
                    score: finalScore,
                    last_date: timeStamp
                };

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it'd be great to update the question with an example of your code.

Comment: done, also I'm actually trying to get the data out with api using a mysql orm

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to send the high score to a specific page and then you can use $_POST in PHP to put it in your database. You can use PHP to save the date, time, score, username, etc. Ensure the game name is unique & use that for PHP to reference which index in the database table you created for game scores.

Here is an example save function from games I help develop (for IBP Arcade or SMF Arcade):

```
function submitScore(score)
{
    let pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/'), newpath = '', currentPath = '';
    for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
        currentPath = pathArray[i].toString().toLowerCase();
        if (currentPath == 'arcade' || currentPath == 'games')
            break;
        newpath += '/' + pathArray[i];
    }
    scorepost(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname.replace(/[/]+$/, '') + '/' + newpath.replace(/^[/]+/, '') + '/index.php?act=Arcade&do=newscore', {
        gname : 'html5_game_name',
        gscore: score
    });
}
```

You'll likely have to edit how it determines the URL a bit. The above function was made for 2 different Arcade's and is designed to work for websites contained in either parent or sub-paths.
Call that function right where you have it using the console log.

To get the high scores from your database to be accessible in your game you can use PHP to create an API page with the basic sought data. Use javascript to call the page with the game name as a reference & then use DOM to gather the data. The HTML on the API page can be contained in a parent pre tag. You can use DOM to access its children that has the data like date, score, user name, etc.